# ASP.NET4.0 MVC4 IIS7.5 Error 403.14 I'm Literally Pulling Out My Hair

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get away from developing in PHP but doing that is proving to be a massive headache.

I am trying to set up a website with MVC 4, ASP.NET 4.0, on Win7 Professional (64-bit). The website is just the basic site that is set up with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express selecting New Project > C# > Website > ASP.NET MVC 4 Application.

After setting up the application in IIS7.5 I am getting an HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. I've done a ton of research and tried multiple different suggestions on how to solve the problem but NOTHING is working. Here are some things I tried:

1. Install/Register v4 of ASP.NET. This has been the most annoying
       thing because everyone else's issue is fixed when they do this but
       mine is not.
2. Changing the application pool settings:

   - Set to classic/integrated mode
   - Change the user/permissions used by the application pool
   - Made sure 32-bit applications were enabled
3. Added security permissions to folders related to the website (on multiple accounts)

I can get a regular html document to show up if I add it to the websites root directory. It seems that the MVC stack is not being called at all. The server wants to display the directory, which I can enable/disable, but the website is not being displayed.
Please can I have more potential fixes before I resort to my last desperate act? A baseball bat.

p.s. I'm more than willing to do a skype conversation or a share screen kind of thing if someone wants to dig in deep. I am beyond frustrated with this.

Comment: What were the security permissions you added? I would try setting the website root to read-only and give `Everyone` full access.

Comment: I suspect that you've mucked with so much stuff that it may be easier to wipe everything and start over.  It's not difficult to get a web site up and running, but if you've mucked with every setting under the book then you could be fighting a larger problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have a vDir, not the required App. Follow my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: @MystereMan I can try setting up a new server on another machine and see if I can get it working. Unfortunately the machine I'm struggling with now is hosting other PHP sites through IIS

Comment: @Jeff I tried giving the permissions you suggested to no avail.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT I'm not using a virtual directory. I am currently trying to access it through a subdomain but that shouldn't be the problem. IIS does not seem to be calling the MVC Routing features -- maybe my MVC is incorrectly installed? Then again, I don't see how that is possible...

Comment: flatten the machine and follow my blog. Create a new MVC 4 app and run under localhost (following my blog). If that fails, create a new ASP.NET web forms app and run on localhost. Don't change the app pool settings. Don't mess with security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems, in my indefinite well of stupidity, I was pointing the webserver to the incorrect folder. I needed to point the webserver to the folder with actual files of the application rather than the folder containing the .SLN file. Sorry to waste your time!

Answer (score 0):

try running the aspnet_regiis
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

open the command line in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` and run

```
aspnet_regiis -ir
```

---

other possible solutions:

- quit skype, or any other similar applications

Comment: Sorry that was the first thing I tried. I said so in the original post.

Comment: maybe you have some firewall, or programs intercept the port, especially skype, close all the apps that you have running

Comment: There are other sites that are working just fine through the same port.

Comment: are they on IIS as well ? or on something else if yes, than you need to stop that (EasyPHP I guess)

Comment: Yes they are running through IIS. It is definitely NOT a port issue.